# How to track sales driven on 3rd party mobile application via affiliate link?

Tags: firebase-analytics, affiliate, appsflyer

We are planning on building a tracking tool to track sales driven from users via affiliate link. We are an aggregator and we plan to run affiliate marketing campaigns for ecommerce companies or brands, example of our business model would be earnkaro.com. We are able to successfully track sales driven from web browser of mobile and desktop. I wanted to understand how can we track the sales for these 2 cases:

1. User does not have app: User opens the affiliate link from mobile and the user clicks on download mobile app. Post downloading the app, user makes a purchase.
2. User has an app: User opens the affiliate link from mobile and makes the purchase.

In the above two cases, link tracking would not be possible as the user has made a sale on the mobile app. However the sale was generated by clicking on an affiliate link.
How to track sales in such case?

We have tried browser based tracking and want to learn about tracking sales driven on 3rd party mobile apps. For example if we are running a campaign for flipkart or meesho, how will we get the sales conversions made by a user after clicking our affiliate link.